# Fade out side of div while having faded color bleed through

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

I'm wondering if there's a way to have a side of a `div` completely faded out (opacity 0) while still having the faded out color bleed through like it does on Sketch or Illustrator. Something like this:

[image: Bottom black, faded out color pink]

Bottom is black, faded out color is pink.

If not, can you do three color gradients? Javascript solutions are fine too.

Comment: As to can you use three color gradient answer is yes

Comment: Maybe play around with something like http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ so you can see what is indeed possible with CSS.  Short answewr to your question is: yes. But you need to put some effort in trying some code :)

Comment: @Paulie_D I've tried the regular approach of just setting one side's rgba opacity value to 0, but that just removes all the color altogether.

Comment: Then **demonstrate** your attempt in a **minimal** demo as is required.

Answer (score 1):

Check css linear-gradient. See example below:

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));

 }
```

```html
<div style="height: 250px; width: 250px">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple colors in the CSS gradient:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #af7caf, #fff);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And by using `rgba` you can change the opacity:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(175, 124, 175, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```